# File does not exists issue with spark2

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to read the file from a directory and getting below error.

Command:

```
val DF = spark.read.format("orc").load("/user/root/dt=2017-04-12/id=100 200")
```

Error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://user/root/dt=2017-04-12/id=100%20200/000000_0

Basically there is space in the directory id=100 200, because of which it is failing.

Could anyone please help me if there is any way to solve.

Answer (score -1):

u can try this `"/user/root/dt=2017-04-12/id=100\\ 200"` or `"/user/root/dt=2017-04-12/"id=100 200""`

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. 

I have tried this but its not working.

Comment: In your error, I have a place that I don't understand, why is there `hdfs`, but there is no `hdfs` related in command.